# perl regex for multi line file

Tags: regex, perl

I have strings like

```
     CASE: 8
     Location: smth
     Destination: 183, 3921,  2.293e-2, 729, 9
     END_CASE
```

I need to put number of CASE (8) and Destination parameters to variables... How to do that?

Comment: `my %data = map split(/:\s*/, $_, 2), split(/\n/, $string);`

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: I've put my input file to @mass and using foreach loop, tryed to check if it matchs with my regexp, but it wont work because it checks line by line...

Comment: @Rocker - If you've made an attempt you must always include that in your question. It will make it easier for people to understand what you're trying to do, and more willing to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is with regexp:

```
my $str = "CASE: 8
Location: smth
Destination: 183, 3921,  2.293e-2, 729, 9
END_CASE
        ";
my ($case,$dest) = $str= m!\A\s*CASE:\s*(\d+).+?Destination:\s*(.+?)\n!gis;
print "case: $case, dest: $dest\n";
```

EDIT:

If you would like to match multiline regexp, and your file is small you could slurp it.

If it is bigger then you could process it in chunks (blocks).

slurp:

```
local $/=undef;
open(my $fh,'<',...) or die $!;
my $str = <$fh>;
while ($str= m!\A\s*CASE:\s*(\d+).+?Destination:\s*(.+?)\n!is){
  print "case: $1, dest: $2\n";
}
```

process in chunks:

```
my $str;
while( my $line = <$fh>){
  if ($line !~ m!END_CASE!){
    $str .= $line;
  } else {
    $str .= $line;
    ### process $str
    my ($case,$dest) = $str= m!\A\s*CASE:\s*(\d+).+?Destination:\s*(.+?)\n!gis;
    print "case: $case, dest: $dest\n";
    ### reset chunk
    $str = '';      
  }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Id like something like while(<$infile>){ if (regexp matchs the text){put collectet arguments into variables)}